# SendBird GET Request Api for retrieve previous messages not working properly

Tags: json, api, sendbird

Im using SendBird platform API to create chat in my website,
when i try to retrieve the previously send messages in a channel using below API:

https://api.sendbird.com/v3/{channel_type}/{channel_url}/messages

METHOD : GET

Request:  ?message_ts=long(Required)&prev_limit=int(Optional, default: 15, 0~200)&next_limit=int(Optional, default: 15, 0~200)&include=boolean(Optional, default: true)&reverse=boolean(Optional, default: false)&custom_type=string(Optional)&message_type=string(Optional)&sender_id=string(Optional)

after passing value to above request,im getting an error saying

{
  "message": "Not authorized. Get messages function can be called only from Park or Enterprise plan.",
  "code": 400108,
  "error": true
}

can some one please help me with this

Thanks
Nithin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Message Retrieval API which you are calling is a premium feature as you can see in Senbird's [Pricing Page](https://sendbird.com/pricing?_ga=1.94612507.648969740.1484435851).

You will have to contact Sendbird and upgrade to their premium plan in order to retrieve message and successfully call the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve messages in SDKs (available for JavaScript too).

In Android call this method,

```
mChannel.getPreviousMessagesByTimestamp()
```

where `mChannel` is an object of type `GroupChannel`(`OpenChannel` also allowed).

And as far as I know, it is ok to retrieve messages like that.

For Javascript 
[refer to this link](https://docs.sendbird.com/javascript#group_channel_one_to_one_chat#open_channel_3_loading_previous_messages)